# How to split one sheet in more keeping references?

Tags: google-sheets

I am using Google spreadsheet and I have a huge amount of data on one Sheet. 
Now, I would like to split that data in more sheets to make everything more structured. How can I move the data from one sheet to another keeping all the references (without rewriting everything on the new sheet)?

Also, If I have used conditional formatting, I want to keep it in my new sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will use formula for that like `QUERY` for example:

```
=QUERY(Sheet1!A:Z, "select A,B,D,E,X", 1)
```

and CF can be copy/pasted

[image]

Comment: please read what I edited in the question about the conditional formatting